# Как правильно добавить html код в отправку почты?

Tags: php, html, email

Есть вот такой код:

```
if(pligg_validate()){
    $encode=md5($_POST['email'] . $user->karma .  $user->username. pligg_hash().$main_smarty->get_config_vars('PLIGG_Visual_Name'));

    $domain = $main_smarty->get_config_vars('PLIGG_Visual_Name');           
    $validation = my_base_url . my_pligg_base . "/validation.php?code=$encode&uid=".urlencode($user->username)."&email=".urlencode($_POST['email']);
    $str = $main_smarty->get_config_vars('PLIGG_PassEmail_verification_message');
    eval('$str = "'.str_replace('"','\"',$str).'";');
    $message = "$str";

    if(phpnum()>=5)
      require("libs/class.phpmailer5.php");
    else
      require("libs/class.phpmailer4.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->From = $main_smarty->get_config_vars('PLIGG_PassEmail_From');
    $mail->FromName = $main_smarty->get_config_vars('PLIGG_PassEmail_Name');
    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['email']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($main_smarty->get_config_vars('PLIGG_PassEmail_From'));
    $mail->IsHTML(false);
    $mail->Subject = $main_smarty->get_config_vars('PLIGG_PassEmail_Subject_verification');
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
```

**PLIGG_PassEmail_verification_message** - это обыкновенное сообщение о регистрации в языковом файле.

```
"Hello $username,\\r\\n\\r\\nWe\'ve sent you this email because you signed up for a new account on $domain. If you didn\'t mean to do that, you can safely ignore this message.\\r\\n\\r\\nVisit this link to activate your account:\\r\\n $validation \\r\\n\\r\\nYour Password is $password \\r\\n\\r\\nIf clicking the link doesn\'t work, copying the complete link address into your browser.\\r\\nStill having trouble? Contact us at $contactmail\\r\\n\\r\\nAfter activation of your account, you can login at $my_base_url$my_pligg_base\\r\\n\\r\\nEnjoy!\\r\\n\\r\\nThe Administrator"
```

Куда правильно добавить [этот](http://pastebin.com/DYcBkaZp) код html?

Comment: Изменил вместо 
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Body = $message;
$message = "$str";

Использую 
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->MsgHTML( $message );
$message = "код html";
Но приходит в письме только  <div dir=

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри заголовки письма, должен быть Content-Type: text/html;
Посмотреть заголовки можно в gmail выбрав пункт меню Показать оригинал.

```
Попробуй добавить в начало <html><head></head><body> и </body></html> в конец.
```